# How do I get the Facebook pixel to fire on a button click on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel

i already have the pixel installed on my site:

```
 <!-- Facebook Pixel Code --> <script> !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod? n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n; n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0; t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'); fbq('init', 'XXXXXXX'); fbq('track', "PageView"); fbq('track', "Lead"); </script> <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1758628277740251&ev=PageView&noscript=1" /></noscript> <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

I have 2 events there, PageView and Lead.

```
                  <script>
              function onClick() {
                fbq('track', 'Lead');
                console.log("clicou");
              };
              </script>
```

and 2 buttons that I would like to track when someone clicks to download my apps.

```
<a href="https://xxxxxxxx" target="_blank" onClick="onClick()"><img src="assets/logos/appstore.png" width="150" alt="Download from App Store" /></a>
```

For some reason the pixel is being fired way more times that my app is actually being download, anyone has an idea of what might he happening ?

Answer (score 1):

please remove  `fbq('track', "Lead");` from the pixel base code, only fire it inside the onClick so it won't get fired when the page load each time.